How to correctly retrieve yesterday's order in Africa/Algiers timezone when using UTC timestamps in Kotlin?
I need help figuring out this special problem I'm having, my users are in africa/algiers. The zone id here is in africa/algiers. When my users place an order the date is of course stored in UTC everywhere in the database, not just the order placed date. Now I have a method that gets the two recent orders (yesterday's order and today's order), the problem is when I try to retrieve the yesterday's order when zoneId is africa/algiers it is given as today's order by my method. This happens when my user places an order between 11pm to 11:59pm in UTC, because africa/algiers is 1h after UTC and when the date is converted back to user's time zone (africa/algiers) it is giving me the next day. But the order was placed yesterday for them and this order should be returned as yesterday's order and not today's order like it is doing now. This is the problem I want to fix, here is my code:
The method that has the issue
fun getRecentOrdersByUser(user: User): Pair<Order?, Order?> {
    val zoneId = getZoneIdFromCountry(user.address.country)

    val today = LocalDate.now(zoneId)
    val yesterday = today.minusDays(1)

    val todayOrder = getUserOrderByStatusAndDate(user, zoneId, date = today)
    val yesterdayOrder = getUserOrderByStatusAndDate(user, zoneId, date = yesterday)

    return yesterdayOrder to todayOrder
}

Here's the remainder of the code that is used my the preceding method
fun getUserOrderByStatusAndDate(
    user: User,
    zoneId: ZoneId,
    status: OrderStatus = OrderStatus.CONFIRMED,
    date: LocalDate = LocalDate.now(zoneId),
): Order? {
    val (startDateTime, endDateTime) = getDateTimeRangeLocal(date, zoneId)
    return orderRepository.findOrderByUserAndStatusAndOrderPlacedDate(
        user = user,
        status = status,
        startDate = startDateTime,
        endDate = endDateTime,
    )
}

fun getDateTimeRangeLocal(date: LocalDate, zoneId: ZoneId): Pair<OffsetDateTime, OffsetDateTime> {
    val startDateTime = date
        .atStartOfDay(zoneId)
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
        .toOffsetDateTime()

    val endDateTime = date
        .atTime(23, 59, 59, 999_999_999)
        .atZone(zoneId)
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
        .toOffsetDateTime()

    return startDateTime to endDateTime
}

findOrderByUserAndStatusAndOrderPlacedDate is a Query in my repository, here it is
@Query("SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE o.user = :user AND o.status = :status AND o.orderPlacedDate >= :startDate AND o.orderPlacedDate <= :endDate ORDER BY o.orderPlacedDate DESC")
fun findOrderByUserAndStatusAndOrderPlacedDate(
    @Param("user") user: User,
    @Param("status") status: OrderStatus,
    @Param("startDate") startDate: OffsetDateTime,
    @Param("endDate") endDate: OffsetDateTime
): Order?

But I don't think the issue is a "bug" that i have in my code but something is missing that calculates the dates correctly in my getRecentOrdersByUser method

How is the date converted back to user's time zone (africa/algiers)? Can you show some correct and incorrect example results?

If you can reduce your code to a [mre], it will greatly help us help you. You may also want to see Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example.

Since you already know what triggers is, this seems super trivial to write an integration test for that reproduces it. Which will make debugging this a breeze, unlike trying to debug it from text.

@deHaar in the getDateTimeRangeLocal(date method

Well, that's why I was asking for example values… I already tried that method and it did not produce any suspicious results. But maybe I did not fully understand your problem — possibly due to missing example results, too.

I'll add these right now

@deHaar
For today
startDateTime: 2024-12-17T23:00Z
endDateTime: 2024-12-18T22:59:59.999999999Z
For yesterday
startDateTime: 2024-12-16T23:00Z
endDateTime: 2024-12-17T22:59:59.999999999Z
My entry I want to get
2024-12-17 23:53:59.64374+00
Why is it not working, this entry with this orderPlacedDate of 2024-12-17 23:53:59.64374+00 should be in yesterday object and not today

That's because endDateTime: 2024-12-17T22:59:59.999999999Z is before 2024-12-17 23:53:59.64374+00. Z and +00 is effectively the same when calculated with OffsetDateTimes, I think. That's why the order is not considered yesterday. But where has the other zone id gone? Do you have any example with the zone id (Algiers) from the question?
